# Blackberry: attaching a document file with blackberry application

Tags: blackberry

I want to attach a file on my blackberry application so that while I am running my app it will install and open that attachment file from application resources. (Blackberry version till 7.1)

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by attach and attachment, as it relates to an application.  How is the file 'attached'?  Also have you reviewed this: http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11935/Create_attachment_handler_565458_11.jsp?

Comment: any document file like txt, doc, xls or jpg. Can we add an option to jad file for download a any file with cod file?